# NSWindow contentView not cover full window size - macOS & SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, fullscreen, nswindow, titlebar

I'm starting a new macOS app with SwiftUI but I have a big problem.
The app needs a full size `contentView` (underneath `titleBar`) but I can't accomplish. On a new project using Storyboards works fine, but with SwiftUI not.

My code:
[image]

Result:
[image]

And it should look like this:
[image]

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: And what's wrong with it? Do you want a window without titlebar?

Comment: Yes, I need a window without titlebar but with close, minimize and resize buttons. Two views (red & black) must be extend under titlebar and buttons

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I just used the following variant in `AppDelegate`, the content of `ContentView` and others can be any

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
    let contentView = ContentView()
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) // to extend entire content under titlebar 

    // Create the window and set the content view. 
    window = NSWindow(
        contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
        styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .texturedBackground, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
        backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    window.center()
    window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")

    window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true // as stated
    window.titleVisibility = .hidden         // no title - all in content

    window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
}
```

Comment: It is interesting that specifying the edges outside of `ContentView` has a different effect. That is either a bug or SwiftUI has more composition problems than I thought. Time for more experiments :) Thanks for your answer!

Comment: For the record: If I have a `NavigationView` inside the `ContentView` I still need an `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` on the `NavigationView` as well.

Comment: Also I had add this `window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false` to prevent crashing while closing the window.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to work on macOS 12. I'm unable to make the sidebar assume the full window height.

Comment: @Bryan I just ran into issues with material / visual effect views not covering the whole window. I assume your sidebar is also a material / visual effect view? When debugging I noticed that using a `Color` it worked fine, but with a material / visual effect I had to use `.frame(minWidth: ,minHeight:)`.

Answer (score 5):

The safe area does not extend underneath a transparent title bar. You can use `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` to tell your content view edges to ignore the safe area. Something that resembles your example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
      Text("Hello, World!")
        .frame(maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.red)
      Text("Hello, World!")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.black)
    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
  }
}
```

**Update:**
If you want to use a NavigationView, you have to add `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` to its contents as well:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Text("Hello, World!")
        .frame(maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.red)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

      Text("Hello, World!")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.black)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this will initially show a title bar at the moment, apparently until you force a full window redraw. Once you move the window to a different display or hide and show it again, the title bar disappears. So, my guess is that this will be fixed at some point.

Right now, you can programmatically force a hide & show by adding

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.window.orderOut(nil)
  self.window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
}
```

after `window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. It will add a very short animation however. If it bothers you, you may be able to turn that off with `NSWindow.animationBehavior` or something like that.

**Update 2**: Apparently, if you remove the initial `window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)` and replace it with the dispatch queue logic above it won't animate. So in the end you'll have

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
  let contentView = ContentView()

  window = NSWindow(
      contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
      styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView, .texturedBackground],
      backing: .buffered, defer: false)
  window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
  window.center()
  window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
  window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
  // window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self) <- don't call it here
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.window.orderOut(nil)
    self.window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: The right way is to use NagivationView. In macOS you shouldn't use HStack for navigation. It works fine with your solution, but not with NavigationView.
I leave this answer in standby pending other options. Thank you!

Comment: You didn't say anything about navigation :) I have updated my answer.

Comment: How is it less accurate?

Comment: It's difficult to evaluate. Both answers are correct, but the other has less code, more general, applies to whole contentView, etc
I've thought a lot about what answer accept as best. If I could, I'd give the points to both of you. I'm sorry... :(

Comment: I can imagine, but I understand that you want to build a reputation.

Answer (score 3):

Just for more information in the case of  SwiftUI App life cycle.

You need to set the window style to HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle :

```
WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
}.windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())
```

Answer (score 1):

Minimal solution in pure SwiftUI.

```
@main
struct X_App: App {

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
       .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) 
           
    }.windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)
 }}
```