# How to have a fully functioning NavigationView in a .fullSizeContent window with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, macos-catalina, navigationview, arrow-keys

I'm trying to get my `NavigationView` to fill the whole window. The `List` should stretch from the top to bottom edge of its window. But while the List looks correct at first with `.fullSizeContentView` added to `NSWindow`'s `styleMask` the whole NavigationView shrinks down as soon as I select a list item.

To Prevent shrinking I found two options.

1. Use a `ZStack` with `Color`-background, so the background will resize `DetailView`.
2. Use a `frame`-modifier with `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` being `.infinity`

Both options will destroy the `List`'s arrow key navigation though.

Which is the correct way to set up full size content with a `NavigationView`?

Below is the complete working sample code needed to replicate the problem. If you you want to test it, just replace the contents of those files in a fresh Swift macOS App on Catalina.

### AppDelegate.swift

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let contentView = ContentView()

        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            // <---- remove .fullSizeContentView mask and layout will work without option 1 or 2 in ContentView
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
        window.titleVisibility = .hidden
        window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }
}
```

### ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

let warners = ["Yacko","Wacko","Dot"]

struct WarnerView: View {
    var name: String
    var body: some View {
//        ZStack { // <---- Option 1: use ZStack with Color.clear
//            Color.clear
            VStack {
                Text(name)
                Text("Nothing to see here!")
            }
//            .frame(minWidth: 100, idealWidth: 100, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, idealHeight: 100, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
//          <---- Option 2: use only VStack with frame
//        } // <- closing bracket for ZStack
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.clear
            NavigationView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Warners")
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                        .padding(16)
                    List(warners, id: \.self)
                     { warner in
                        NavigationLink(destination: WarnerView(name: warner)
                        ) {
                            Text(warner)
                        }
                    }.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
                }
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .frame(minWidth: 600, minHeight: 400)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood here is way (tested with Xcode 12 / macOS 10.15.6). No changes to your above `WarnerView`.

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                  HStack {
                        Text("Warners")
                             .font(.headline)
                  }
                  ForEach(warners, id: \.self)
                    { warner in
                        NavigationLink(destination:
                            WarnerView(name: warner)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                                ) {
                             Text(warner)
                        }
                  }
                }.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())

// uncomment below for default details area
//                  WarnerView(name: "")
//                      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I guess this is missing the .fullSizeContentView in AppDelegate.swift. So The hidden titlebar is visible.

Comment: On *missing the .fullSizeContentView* - no, `.fullSizeContentView` is present. If you want to hide titlebar that is different question - consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/60252103/12299030.

Comment: I think it's not a different question since I asked for that: `I'm trying to get my NavigationView to fill the whole window. The List should stretch from the top to bottom edge of its window.` I did set `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` as proposed in your answer seen via the link. Only I set it in ContentView.swift, not in AppDelegate. Moving it over to AppDelegate does not seem to have any effect on the problem. The list is not navigatable with arrow-keys.