# How can I hide statusBar of a View/Window in macOS in SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I was trying to hide **statusBar** of a view but I noticed it does not work in macOS, also **Blur** did not worked also **opacity** did not work! it look like I am trying programming new language, apple said code in place and apply every where! why I can not done those simple task in macOS?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {        
        HStack {
            Button { print("OK was clicked!") } label: { Text("OK").frame(width: 100) }
            Button { print("Close was clicked!") } label: { Text("Close").frame(width: 100) }
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 200)
        .background(Color.white.opacity(0.4).blur(radius: 0.5))
        //.statusBar(hidden: true)
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct macOSApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60252103/12299030?

Comment: thanks also I am not seeing App Delegate!?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you. 
Thank you.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

    // Create the content view, to display the contents
    let contentView = ContentView()
    //to display content view beyond status bar.
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)  

    // Now, just create the window and set the content view. 
    window = NSWindow(
        contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
        styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .texturedBackground, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
        backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    window.center()
    window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
    
    //So, this does the maigc
    //Hides the titlebar.
    window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true 
    window.titleVisibility = .hidden        

    window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
}
}
```

Comment: I do not see App Delegate in my project, I made a screenshot

Comment: In your, macOsApp.swift. you can the below line in the macosApp struct, `@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate` & add copy & paste the editted answer somewhere in that file.

Comment: Can you explain more, I can not get it working or maybe a example