# Config application's titlebar width to some values

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Firstly, I want to show my code to config my application's titlebar:

```
    let customToolbar = NSToolbar()
    customToolbar.showsBaselineSeparator = false
    window?.toolbar = customToolbar
    window?.titleVisibility = .hidden
    window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
```

This is the result:
[image]

However, the title bar's width is still spanning through all application's width. I want to make it narrows to some area only. For example, Apple Music's interface

[image]

In the Apple's Music case, it looks like toolbar and titlebar is on the same row.

How can I do this in SwiftUI 1.0?

My apologies because I don't know to express the problem better. I am happy to add more information in case I missed something.

Comment: That looks like a TableView with multiple sections

Comment: @LeoDabus You mean Apple Music or my application? In case my application, I don't use TableView

Comment: Apple Music ...

Comment: So you mean close/minimize/maximize buttons don't belong to the titlebar but they implement again by themselves ?

Comment: It looks like a sidebar and a tableview https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/sidebars/

Comment: This is just the guideline, right? My question is how can we make close/minimize/maximize button (e.g: titlebar) as in the Apple Music.

Comment: As I said IMO this looks like it is achieved using a sidebar with a table view

Comment: P/S: some guys want to close this question without any comment to improve. If you consider this question is not good, at least put a comment. Please be professional.

Comment: Not my vote but people have the right to vote if they think there is something wrong with the question

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/split-views/ and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssplitviewcontroller

Comment: What you are looking for is a splitviewcontroller with transparent title bar,  title hidden and full size content view. https://www.dropbox.com/s/yth9vit9n72wu4b/full%20size%20content%20view.png?dl=1

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much. Let me try :D But from your image, it seems what I am looking for.

Comment: They use full content size with hidden title bar. This should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/60252103/12299030

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for Cocoa is to use a splitviewcontroller with transparent title bar, title hidden and full size content view. If you would like to accomplish the same with SwiftUI you need to use a HSplitView, set your content view `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)`, set your `titleVisibility` hidden and your window `titlebarAppearsTransparent` to true.