# NSWindow - hiding titlebar while keeping control buttons with Cocoa/AppKit (NOT SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift5, nswindow

I'm building a macOS (OSX) application with XCode and I'm trying to get rid of the titlebar (maybe it's called toolbar?) in top of the window while still keeping the 3 control buttons (*close*, *minimize* and *full screen*).

So far I'm only able to hide this bar while keeping the buttons, but it looks like the bar is still there somehow. My `NSTableViews` recognize this as the bar and create some sort of transparent safe area before the rows and headers.

Here is what I got so far:
[image]

And here is what I want:
[image]

Notice that application is using UIKit and storyboards - NOT SwiftUI. The green area to the left is a sidebar of a `NSSplitView`. Just so you understand the structure.

I have these attributes set for the `NSWindow` at the moment:
[image]

- Deployment target: macOS 12
- XCode: 13.1
- Swift: 5

Thanks!

Comment: I've read this but it seems that the answers were all related to SwiftUI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65367400/config-applications-titlebar-width-to-some-values

Comment: You probably meant Cocoa. My answer tells how to accomplish it using Cocoa and SwiftUI. Not sure what else you need.

Comment: @LeoDabus Cocoa, yes! This is my first macOS application - coming from mobile ;-) I'm not interested in using SwiftUI, so I'm looking for a solution that does not require this. Do I miss something?

Comment: @LeoDabus see my attached screenshot in the edited post. I have the settings you mention set already, but I still have the invisible top space in the columns of tableviews as described in the post...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish what you are looking for by setting the window's title bar to transparent, hide its title text and set its appearance to Full Size Content View.

[image]

[Sample Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0pcmpdpuje90tp7/Split%20View%20Sample.zip?dl=1)

If you would like to have your table view ignore the top inset you need to set its enclosing scroll view `automaticallyAdjustsContentInsets` property to `false`

[image]

```
scrollView.automaticallyAdjustsContentInsets = false
```

Comment: Hi again Leo. Please read my question... The problem is not hiding the bar and putting a button there - it's the tableviews that have an issue with the hidden titlebar. Try replacing your "Users"-button with a NSTableView and set the spacing constraints to 0's to fill up the full view. You will see the weird spacing above the headers too - I tested your sample project and got the same result.

Comment: perfect! This is what I'm looking for! :-)