# macOS SwiftUI, content does not fill NSWindow without titlebar

Tags: macos, cocoa, swiftui, nswindow

I'm trying to create a custom NSWindow where I want my content to completely fill the available space, I have managed to hide the navigation bar buttons and title and make it transparent, but when I set the content to fill the available space there is some space at the bottom that is not working

[image: window with space at the bottom]

The way I create my window:

```swift
  private func createWindow() -> MyWindow {
    let window = MyWindow(
      contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10), // these values don't matter, the window expands to the swiftUI view
      styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .fullSizeContentView],
      backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    
    window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    window.titleVisibility = .hidden
    window.isMovableByWindowBackground = false
    window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
    window.collectionBehavior = [.transient, .ignoresCycle]
    window.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
    window.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
    window.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
    return window
  }
```

And on my component, I added the following property:

```swift
.ignoresSafeArea()
```

I already followed all the suggestions in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60218622/nswindow-contentview-not-cover-full-window-size-macos-swiftui) but nothing seems to work on my case, any help is appreciatted

Comment: Works fine here - Xcode 13.1 / macOS 12.0.1. Probably there is some issue with SwiftUI view which you place in this window (or with your `MyWindow`, because I tested with `NSWindow`).

Comment: I tried with another SwiftUI which is very simple, just a text and a background color and the behavior is still the same, there is some space at the bottom which is not filled properly :(

Comment: Also tried with a pure NSWindow, also not working

Comment: @Asperi maybe you can provide a running example?

Comment: @OscarFranco: what is MyWindow in your code?

Comment: I got rid of it, it was just setting canBecomeKey to true

Comment: So you are trying to return what then? It seems you have working code on pic

Comment: The code on the pic is the component itself, but it is not so important, the instance of the window just gets returned and then a HostingView is created... You should check out the first answer and the comments below, it looks like SwiftUI is broken when dealing with backgrounds on VStacks

Comment: You are not showing your used code, you are trying to return NSWindow, the link in your question has deferent approach. How you are trying use NSWindow in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks I've reproduced what you might have

```
window.contentView = 
  NSHostingView(rootView: 
     Rectangle().fill(Color.red)
       .ignoresSafeArea()                 // << works !!
       .frame(width: 640, height: 480)
    // .ignoresSafeArea()             // << issue when here !!
  )
```

**More findings:** no issue even with `ignoresSafeArea` at the end when to use min W/H instead of strict frame for window, ie.

```
.frame(minWidth: 640, minHeight: 480)
.ignoresSafeArea()
```

Comment: weird... not working for me (using a VStack and a text inside)... could it also be because I'm using a real swiftUI struct in its own file?

Comment: I have doubts in that. The issue is really with `ignoresSafeArea` modifier.

Comment: Well... I just tried with VStack and background and it seems like drawing the background is the thing that fails?

VStack {
      Rectangle().fill(Color.red)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
    
    .ignoresSafeArea()                 // << works !!
    .frame(width: 640, height: 480)
    .background(Color.blue)

Comment: See updated part - as tested it works even with .background at the end.

Comment: Still not working for me on a VStack, but it does work if I use a ZStack and draw the rectangle manually as a background